# working with ibeacon and PagerSlidingTabStrip

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, ibeacon, pagerslidingtabstrip

I'm working with ibeacon and PagerSlidingTabStrip and I'm okay to update the card contents

I set up a power adapter class to make the call the notifyDataSetChanged () method, example:

```
public class SuperAwesomeCardFragment extends Fragment {

        private static final String ARG_POSITION = "position";

        private int position;

        private ArrayAdapter<Beacon> beaconArrayAdapter;

        public static SuperAwesomeCardFragment newInstance(int position) {
            SuperAwesomeCardFragment f = new SuperAwesomeCardFragment();
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt(ARG_POSITION, position);
            f.setArguments(b);
            return f;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            position = getArguments().getInt(ARG_POSITION);
        }

        public void replaceWith(Collection<Beacon> newBeacons) {
            beaconArrayAdapter.clear();
            beaconArrayAdapter.addAll(newBeacons);
            beaconArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

            FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
            fl.setLayoutParams(params);

            final int margin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 8, getResources()
                    .getDisplayMetrics());

            ListView listView = new ListView(container.getContext());
            listView.setAdapter(this.beaconArrayAdapter);
            listView.setLayoutParams(params);
            listView.setDividerHeight(25);
            fl.addView(listView);
            return fl;
        }
    }
```

Rode also an activity where the value is displayed, but when I run the project, I get the following message: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!! example:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1234;

    private static final Region ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS_REGION = new Region("rid", null, null, null);

    private BeaconManager beaconManager;

    private ActionBar actionBar;

    private PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs;

    private ViewPager pager;

    private MyPagerAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.actionBar = getActionBar();
        if (this.actionBar != null) {
            this.actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

        tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        final int pageMargin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 4, getResources()
                .getDisplayMetrics());
        pager.setPageMargin(pageMargin);

        tabs.setViewPager(pager);
        // Configure verbose debug logging.
        L.enableDebugLogging(true);

        // Configure BeaconManager.
        beaconManager = new BeaconManager(this);
        beaconManager.setRangingListener(new BeaconManager.RangingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBeaconsDiscovered(Region region, final List<Beacon> beacons) {
                // Note that results are not delivered on UI thread.
                Log.e(TAG, "onBeaconsDiscovered");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.e(TAG, "run");
                        // Note that beacons reported here are already sorted by estimated
                        // distance between device and beacon.
                        if (actionBar != null) {
                            actionBar.setSubtitle("Found beacons: " + beacons.size());
                        }
                        if (beacons.size() > 1) {
                            adapter.replaceWith(beacons);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        beaconManager.disconnect();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // Check if device supports Bluetooth Low Energy.
        if (!beaconManager.hasBluetooth()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Device does not have Bluetooth Low Energy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        // If Bluetooth is not enabled, let user enable it.
        if (!beaconManager.isBluetoothEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        } else {
            connectToService();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        try {
            beaconManager.stopRanging(ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS_REGION);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error while stopping ranging", e);
        }

        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                connectToService();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth not enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (this.actionBar != null) {
                    this.actionBar.setSubtitle("Bluetooth not enabled");
                }
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private void connectToService() {
        if (this.actionBar != null) {
            this.actionBar.setSubtitle("Scanning...");
        }

        beaconManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceReady() {
                try {
                    beaconManager.startRanging(ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS_REGION);
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cannot start ranging, something terrible happened",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e(TAG, "Cannot start ranging", e);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private final String[] TITLES = {"Categories", "Home", "Top Paid", "Top Free", "Top Grossing", "Top New Paid",
                "Top New Free", "Trending"};

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return TITLES[position];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return TITLES.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return SuperAwesomeCardFragment.newInstance(position);
        }

        public void replaceWith(Collection<Beacon> newBeacons) {
            replaceWith(newBeacons);
        }
    }
}
```

I understand that I am bursting the available space, but did not understand how to make this process of updating the card correctly. Can anyone explain to me how do it, where is my mistake?

Tnks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand what I did wrong! The code above shows some errors like recursion of replaceWith method.

Tnks people!